# Place fast-growing table on another data file

Tags: postgresql

I am a postgres newbie and could not find the answer in the documentation or from google. Please help me out.

We have a fast-growing table whose content which will be periodically off-loaded to a file and then the table will be vacuumed and cleaned.

The table however grows rapidly and can use up 20% of the anticipated size of the database to 80+%. In some cases it could reach 100% of the volume size due to bad capacity planning. Also, this table has the highest write volume and it would be better to offload it into another volume that has a better write performance. hence we want to handle this table specifically in another location.

The growth rate is about 1GB/hour. There is only about one hour of activity per day though. The cleanup happens at 45 days, so 45GB of data is generated. We delete a month's worth of data, so the db size goes down to 15GB again.

Is it possible to place a fast-growing table (which is periodically cleaned and vacuumed) into a separate file in a separate volume in postgresql? I want it to be part of the same database, but only on a different file.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

Comment: Thank you very much @a_horse_with_no_name! This answers my question. I did not do my due diligence it seems. Should I close the question?

Comment: The question is fundamentally alright. It might be useful to edit it and describe in some more detail what you want to do ("periodically cleaned"?) and why you expect that putting these data elsewhere could be a benefit. If we understand that, we might be able to give a real answer.

Comment: What is "fast" ? But this looks like a candidate for table partitioning where you can drop (or truncate) an entire partition instead of delete and vacuum. This would reduce IO needed. Moving a table partition to a different table space is also possible.

Comment: Thanks for the question @FrankHeikens. Fast is about 1 GB per hour (but only one hour of activity per day) and cleanup happens at 45 days. Will update the question